# Does Q# support web development?

Tags: web-development-server, q#

I have read articles from different sites, cause I didn't wanna install it without knowing how it works first. I was wondering if Q#, a new programming language developed by Microsoft, supports web development?

Comment: Q# is a language designed for quantum computing.  Why would you think that has anything to do with web development?

Comment: FYI: There is a dedicated quantum computing StackExchange site: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

**Q# wasn't made for this purpose.** Q# is a domain specific language for quantum algorithms. As [Microsoft says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/quantum-qr-intro?view=qsharp-preview): it is to be used for writing sub-programs that execute on an adjunct quantum processor, under the control of a classical host program and computer.

However, the Q# language is [compatible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/quantum-writeaquantumprogram?view=qsharp-preview&tabs=tabid-vs2017) with .NET Framework, and you could build a web server with it. <strike>I wonder why in the world would you do that?</strike>

After all, as of today, Q# code is transpiled into C# code. Also, Q# has interoperability with other languages like [Python](https://github.com/Microsoft/Quantum/tree/master/Interoperability/python).

Answer (score 0):

No, because Q# is not a general-purpose programming language.

Let me give you an analogy, Q# is a special-purpose language like Nvidia CUDA. CUDA is used for GPU programming and same way Q# is "to be used" for programming quantum computer. GPU and Quantum computer are more like secondary processing device which are controlled and managed by CPU.

Now coming back to your question, Just think, can you make a web application using CUDA? No, because CUDA is not for primary computing. But of course, you can use CUDA for graphics-intensive tasks like video encoding, image rendering. Same way if there is some task in your business logic which can be done better on a quantum computer, then you can offload that task to the quantum computer. Q# is meant for such scenario.